# How to post a link with a picture to Facebook using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried two different methods.

The first is to specify the link in the `/PROFILE_ID/feed` link argument (as described under "publishing" [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)).  The problem is that if I specify anything other than my application URL i get an error saying the URL is invalid.

The second is to use the `/PROFILE_ID/links` method and specifying a picture URL.  The problem is that when it posts it only shows the message and the URL.  I've specified values for picture, name and message but none of them show.

How can I Post a link, with a name, message and picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by using the `/PROFILE_ID/feed` method and then disabling `Stream post URL security` in my application security settings.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Where do you disable that settings?

Answer (score 5):

Your first approach is the correct one. Is your url starting with http://? What SDK are you using?

As described on this page, the example suggest it should work.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
 -F 'message=Check out this funny article' \
 -F 'link=http://www.example.com/article.html' \
 -F 'picture=http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg' \
 -F 'name=Article Title' \
 -F 'caption=Caption for the link' \
 -F 'description=Longer description of the link' \
 -F 'actions={"name": "View on Zombo", "link": "http://www.zombo.com"}' \
 -F 'privacy={"value": "ALL_FRIENDS"}' \
 -F 'targeting= {"countries":"US","regions":"6,53","locales":"6"}' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

Comment: I am using an unsupported open source C# SDK.  I was able to fix this using the method I posted below.

Comment: Right, is it the SSL certificate verification you had to disable?

Comment: Being an old post, this answer helped me to post image with message, link and url using new version in nodejs. Thanks